# php not showing bold index

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on php and MySQL. I have put example data to my database with index but it does not show in my browser. I have followed this youtuber and it seems like it works fine for him.

This is mine not showing the index

[image: Not showing index]

this is my code for my database

```
<?php

    require_once('mysqli_connect.php');

    $query = "SELECT id, email, phone, firstName, lastName, 
    anniversary, birthday, sign_up_date FROM Customer_Info";

    $response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if($response){

        echo '<table align="left"
        cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8">

        <tr><td align="left"><b><Email Address></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b><Phone></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b><First Name></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b><Last Name></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b><Anniversary></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b><Birthday></b></td>
        <td align="left"><b><Signed Up Date></b></td></tr>';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){

            echo '<tr><td align=left">'.
            $row['email'] . '</td><td align="left">' .
            $row['phone'] . '</td><td align="left">' .
            $row['firstName'] . '</td><td align="left">' .
            $row['lastName'] . '</td><td align="left">' .
            $row['anniversary'] . '</td><td align="left">' .
            $row['birthday'] . '</td><td align="left">' .
            $row['sign_up_date'] . '</td><td align="left">';

            echo '</tr>';

        }

        echo '</table>';    

    } else{

        echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";

        echo mysqli_error($dbc);
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

And this is what it suppose to look like

[image: Intended look]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text inside an element shouldn't be in angle brackets.

```
<b><Email Address></b>
```

should be

```
<b>Email Address</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
  <strong>
```

instead of

```
   <b>
```

its been deprecated! 
And I doubt modern browsers will still render them

Comment: I still have problem T-T

Answer (score 0):

Use `<th>` tag instead of `<td>` for the header. And pay attention to what @Display Name have said